# Remove gridlines around range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in a worksheet that has a range of A1:T16. I want to remove all gridlines outside this range of cells. I can remove all gridlines with the code below but not for a specific range.

```
Windows("New Initiative Template VBA v3.xlsm").DisplayGridlines = False
```

Comment: Gridlines are a sheet-level setting. Do you mean cell borders?

Comment: Yes, cell borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are millions of examples online. Perhaps you could change the title of your question?

```
Range("A1:T16").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
```